# How to add a layout file to only take half the page of Android activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

Basically, I want to have a pop-up box to appear so that the user can fill out the form as opposed to going to the next page.

I am not sure how to do it, but I have included a picture of what I want

[image]

Its how I put my xml file like that into that activity

Thanks

Comment: dont use pop up dialog instead use activity

Comment: even easier with [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html), which you can style as you want (usual dialogs also ofc)

Comment: I am trying to stray away from the `AlertDialog.Builder` as much as possible, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: You should use a `DialogFragment`, and override the method `onCreateView`, where you can pass the layout you want.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I am new to android development

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragment is the best way to do.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html

also you can use Framelayout.
it's easy to do some customization.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     tools:context="com.example.zhangjunyi.testfornet.MainActivity">
>
>     <FrameLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         //your activity layout 
>     </FrameLayout>
>
>
>     <FrameLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:visibility="gone">
>
>         //your dialog view, may do some custome
>         //may use some animation to show, when the animation end >  >             //set the view visible, use a transparent background for
>          // the view make
>         //it looks like a dialog.
>
>
>     </FrameLayout>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dialog view to add UI and perform task on it in the same activity. Here you have to set layout with UI as you want.

```
public void showDialog( Context context ) {

    Dialog mDialog;

    mDialog = new Dialog(context);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();

    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dlg_rating_bar_);
    TextView tvMessage = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dlg_tv_message);
    EditText etComment = (EditText) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dlg_et_comment);
    Button btnAdd = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dlg_btn_add);
    Button btnDiscard = (Button) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dlg_btn_discard);

    // do your stuff here

}
```

Comment: How do I set it so that it only shows 5 stars? I am having some difficulty with that at the moment

Comment: Check this link, you will get solution to your problem. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/